# How to define an accessor for an existing field in a model in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a model called `Book` for a table called `books`, that has a field called `cover_image`.

However, I want to define an accessor for the field `cover_image` instead of just retrieving the default value.

This is how I attempted to do this:

```
class Book extends Model {

    public function getCoverImageAttribute() {

         if ($this->cover_image === null) { // Not sure how to check current value?
               return "a.jpg"
         }
         return $this->cover_image; 
    } 

}
```

However the above of course does not work because calling `$this->cover_image` again would cause recursion

How can I fix this?

Comment: You might want to use php 7 syntax for null coercion

`return $this->cover_image ?? "a.jpg"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must check for the attribute instead:

```
class Book extends Model {

    public function getCoverImageAttribute() {
         return $this->attributes['cover_image'] ?? "a.jpg"; 
    } 

}
```

This will allow you to normally use `$book->cover_image` as well.

I believe the following example will also work:

```
class Book extends Model {

    public function getCoverImageAttribute($value) {    

         return is_null($value) ? 'a.jpg' : $value; 
    } 

}
```